# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dockerstats'

Tags: r, lazy-loading, renv

I have not been able to install the dockerstats package from github since I installed the renv package. when I run `remotes::install_github("ColinFay/dockerstats")` I receive this errors:

```
> remotes::install_github("ColinFay/dockerstats")
Downloading GitHub repo ColinFay/dockerstats@HEAD
Running `R CMD build`...
Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 2 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

* checking for file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpu6shLo\remotes4c04aa134e0\ColinFay-dockerstats-2f15876/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'dockerstats':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'dockerstats_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Warning message:
This project is configured to use R version '4.1.1', but '4.0.2' is currently being used. 
* installing *source* package 'dockerstats' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dockerstats'
* removing 'C:/Users/user/Documents/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/dockerstats'
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
3: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpu6shLo/file4c07a23d81/dockerstats_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I fix this issue and install the package?
Please help! Thank you so much

Comment: Have you docker desktop installed ?

Comment: “This project is configured to use R version '4.1.1', but '4.0.2' is currently being used.” — This is an issue, you need to fix it! You’re using the wrong R version for the project.

Comment: I fixed it by deactivating renv package. thanks all